# Do I need a transit visa to go from Narita to Haneda?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas, japan, filipino-citizens

Two weeks from now (Oct. 22), I will land at Narita airport at 3 P.M. and then transfer directly to Haneda airport for my connecting flight to Manila at 1 A.M. on Oct. 23; this is a 9-hour layover and I have no plan to travel outside of Tokyo for pleasure. The embassy told me to get a transit visa, but is it applicable in my situation? Is there any exemption? I am a Philippine citizen.

Comment: Where are you starting your journey to Narita from?

Comment: Where journey started is irrelevant. As you are not visa-exempt country citizen you need visa to get out of terminal. Very likely your flight company will not allow you to board without visa, but if they will you will be sent back to your origin.

Comment: Maybe, but strongly recommended. Shore Passes are possible but not exactly very easy.